# What is the origin of "Breaking in" as in a shoe or glove?

Tags: etymology

Questions says it all. Why do we call it "breaking in" when we refer to relaxing the stiffness of worn objects/tools? This use of break is similar to the "breaking the spirit" or a wild animal. But otherwise it doesn't follow from the regular mean of break, which implies the object will no longer function. In this case, the function of the object is improved.

Comment: Ugh. The OED doesn't even mention this sense of *break*, so I don't know for sure when it originated. I do know that it at least goes back to [1884](https://books.google.com/books?id=IMoWAQAAIAAJ&pg=PA121&dq="broken+in").

Comment: I've always assumed that it refers to flexing newly-tanned leather, to remove the stiffness.  In flexing the leather object you would do motions that would "break" a stick or other more substantial object.

Comment: Etymology Online: *Old English brecan "to divide solid matter violently into parts or fragments; to injure, violate (a promise, etc.), destroy, curtail; to break into, rush into; to burst forth, spring out; to subdue, tame" (class IV strong verb; past tense bræc, past participle brocen), from Proto-Germanic *brekan (source also of Old Frisian breka, Dutch breken, Old High German brehhan, German brechen, Gothic brikan), from PIE root *bhreg- "to break."*  Note "tame" in the list.

Comment: @Laurel, it does. Please see 'break something in' in [OED](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/break)

Comment: @alexsms Your reference is from EOLD ("English Oxford Living Dictionaries") not from the OED (Oxford English Dictionary). There is considerable difference between the two.

Comment: Note taken, thanks. I've seen some people here use the 3 letter abbreviation OED with a link to 'online living'.

Comment: The concept of breaking in shoes/boots was definitely under discussion in the early 1870s.  I'll try to compose a full answer later when I have time. The term "break-in" was often in quotes, suggesting (to me, at least) that it was a relatively recently adopted term.

Answer (score 7):

I think it probably is an extension of the earlier transitive usage of “break in”  meaning teaching  or training someone to do a new job, on the notion of “training” your new shoes till they become more confortable.

***[Break in](https://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/break+in) :***

> - Train or instruct someone in a new job or enterprise, as in *Every semester she had to break in a new teaching assistant. [Late 1700s]*
> - Loosen or soften with use, as in *It takes a while to break in a pair of new shoes.*

(AHD)

The expression appears to be from the second half of the 19th century; the earliest example I could find is from a 1867 edition of "[A Japanese and English Dictionary](https://books.google.it/books?id=panQAAAAMAAJ&pg=PA342&dq=%22break%20in%20a%20new%20pair%22&hl=it&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwiK5d-7sJbZAhXCUhQKHbzIC5gQ6AEIJzAA#v=onepage&q=%22break%20in%20a%20new%20pair%22&f=false)"

> - to break in a new pair of sandals.

Comment: It refers to horses, which is thousands of years earlier.

Comment: @smci - also in that case it is a question   of training.

Comment: I know that. My point is there were domesticated horses thousands of years before there were office jobs.

Answer (score 2):

I always thought that it came from the fact that, by using the thing more, you are breaking down and stretching out the materials of the object, making it more comfortable because now it's been appropriated for your foot, hand, etc.
Don't quote me on that though, just a guess.

Answer (score 2):

It most likely originates as an analogy to the process of [breaking in a horse](http://www.hartstoneequestrian.com/Horse-Training/Breaking-In), though nowadays this appears to be more commonly known as "breaking a horse" or even just ["horse training"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Horse_training).

From [What is Broke Horse?](https://www.thespruce.com/what-is-broke-horse-1886596) on The Spruce:

> Many people don't like the term 'broke' because it suggests training done by force or by breaking the horse’s spirit. When horses were rounded up off the range and ‘bucked out’ by a rough rider who wanted to quickly make them useful, this might have been true.

Comment: I agree. You have to 'break in' a young horse before you can ride it, and you might have to do some work on a stiff leather garment/pair of shoes before it is comfortable.

Comment: Why do you think the meaning of the term didn't originate from the leather manufacturing sense of 'to break', that is "to scrape a skin smooth and clean on the flesh side"?

Comment: @JEL, I wasn't familiar with that usage.  It's another possibility, certainly.